# How can I read very old iChat transcripts?

Tags: macos, file-format, ichat

Sometime in 2005, Apple's iChat switched to writing its logs as binary plists. But before that, it was another format that I don't know how to read.

```
> file some-early-2005-log.chat
some-early-2005-log.chat: NeXT/Apple typedstream data, big endian, version 4, system 1000
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that kind of file was created when apps used the NSArchiver APIs to serialize objects to a file on disk. That means it's very closely linked to the object classes in the app that created it. It's not a good way to make a portable file that can be shared with other apps, which is probably why abandoned it and moved on to something more portable like plists.

I think you're mostly out of luck without the c. 2004-2005 iChat AV codebase. You could use the `strings(1)` command to extract strings from those files, but you'd probably miss the dates, which are probably binary encoded.

Glancing at one of my old .chat files from that era in a hex editor, it looks like there's a 32-bit "seconds since the Unix epoch" timestamp a few bytes before each chat message string, and a 2-byte length value immediately preceding each chat message string. There's some stuff at the beginning of the file that tells who's chatting, and which font settings they're using.